# kotlin generics in KFunction1

Tags: generics, kotlin

Suppose, you have two classes TestA and TestB. Suppose that TestA extends TestB:

```
public class TestB {
    private int intProp;
    public int getIntProp() {
        return intProp;
    }
    public void setIntProp(int intProp) {
        this.intProp = intProp;
    }
}


public class TestA extends TestB {
    private String strProp;
    public String getStrProp() {
        return strProp;
    }
    public void setStrProp(String strProp) {
        this.strProp = strProp;
    }
}
```

Now I create next line of code:

```
var getter1: KFunction1<TestA, Int> = TestA::getIntProp
```

As you can see, I access from TestA class method of TestB: TestA::getIntProp
SO the result is instance of KFunction1 with generic params < TestA, Int >

Now I try to create next line of code

```
var getter2: KFunction1<TestA, Int> = TestB::getIntProp
```

And it also works and compiles, while I expect that there will be compile error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [generics variance in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance), its purpose is to impose type-safe hierarchy on generic classes with parameters which are in class hierarchy themselves.

Class `KFunction1` has generic parameters defined as `<in P1, out R>`, `P1` with `in` modifier and `R` with `out` modifier. This means that there will be:

- **Contravariance on** `P1` introduced by `in` modifier.

  Any `KFunction1<PSuper, R>` will be a subtype of `KFunction1<P, R>` if `PSuper` is a supertype of `P`. But the limitation will be added that `P1` can only appear as argument of (passed into) `KFunction1`'s members.
- **Covariance on** `R` introduced by `out` modifier.

  Any `KFunction1<P, RSub>` will be a subtype of `KFunction1<P, R>` if `RSub` is a subtype of `R`. And here `R` will be limited: it can only be used as a return value (passed out) of `KFunction1`'s members.

Therefore you will be able to assign `KFunction1<PSuper, RSub>` to a variable of type `KFunction1<P, R>`.

This makes sense for `KFunction1`, because any function that receives an argument of type `PSuper` can also receive an instance of `P` (but not vice versa), and any function that returns instances of `RSub` in the same time returns instances of `R` (but not vice versa).

---

You can simply compose an example which shows this behaviour:

```
class Invariant<T>  {
    fun f(i: Int): T { throw Exception() } // OK
    fun f(t: T): Int { throw Exception() } // OK
}

class Contravariant<in T> {
    fun f(i: Int): T { throw Exception() } // error, T cannot be returned
    fun f(t: T): Int { throw Exception() } // OK, T is parameter type
}

class Covariant<out T> {
    fun f(i: Int): T { throw Exception() } // OK, T is returned
    fun f(t: T): Int { throw Exception() } // error, T cannnot be parameter type
}

open class Base
class Derived: Base()

val i1: Invariant<Base> = Invariant<Derived>() // error
val i2: Invariant<Derived> = Invariant<Base>() // error

val n1: Contravariant<Base> = Contravariant<Derived>() // error
val n2: Contravariant<Derived> = Contravariant<Base>() // OK

val v1: Covariant<Base> = Covariant<Derived>() // OK
val v2: Covariant<Derived> = Covariant<Base>() // error
```

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks!